# Are there countries in which the "price" paid in a prisoner exchange deals is restricted by law?

Tags: international, war

When terrorist organizations capture hostages, sometimes the captives' country tries to negotiate a deal, which often includes prisoner exchange. The "price" for such deals may be very high. For example, in the [Gilad Shalit prisoner exchange deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilad_Shalit_prisoner_exchange), Israel released 1027 Arab prisoners in exchange to a single Israeli soldier.

QUESTION:

- Is there a country in which the "price" that the government is allowed to pay during prisoner exchange is bounded by law, for example, "a prisoner deal may only be in one-for-one ratio"?
- Is there a country in which hostage deals are restricted by law in any other way?

Comment: In some countries (e.g. UK) the public stance is "we do not negotiate with terrorists" so a law which proscribes the details would be unusual. If it *does* happen it would be 'under the table'. Anyway, I don't see how any law could set out an equation along the lines of "X enemy terrorists = Y proud soldiers".

Comment: ... or a scale by rank, where one private is worth... one colonel is worth...  X terrorists.

Comment: @WeatherVane Making proper change would certainly be an issue.